# Given a point $P$ outside equilateral $\Delta ABC$ but inside $\angle ABC$, if the distance between $P$ to $BC,CA,AB$ are $h_1,h_2,h_3$ respectively.

Tags: geometry, triangles, problem-solving

> Given a point $P$ outside equilateral $\Delta ABC$ but inside $\angle ABC$, if the distance between $P$ to $BC,CA,AB$ are $h_1,h_2,h_3$ respectively, where $h_1 - h_2 + h_3 = 6$, find $[\Delta ABC]$ .

**What I Tried**: At first I couldn't understand if $h_1,h_2,h_3$ are just any lines touching the sides or are some specific lines like altitudes or medians (bisecting the sides of the triangle) . But since they are denoted like $h_1,h_2,h_3$ I suppose they are the altitudes. So here is a picture :-

[image]

No idea for this problem. I don't think I can use any simple geometry techniques here like angle-chasing, area of triangles, pythagorean theorem and so on, because I have been given very less info. So I am a bit stuck here.

Can anyone help me? Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Viviani's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviani%27s_theorem), the height of $\triangle ABC$ is $6$, so its side length is $\frac{12}{\sqrt3}=4\sqrt3$ and its area is $\frac{6×4\sqrt3}2=12\sqrt3$.

Comment: Okay I think this looks the easiest answer. I didn't think about that.

Comment: The Wikipedia article did not cover the case where $P$ is not in the interior of the triangle. [This](https://ggijro1.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/art44311.pdf) does, and its proof reduces to height and area manipulations.

Comment: @MathLover wrong, Wikipedia does cover the exterior-point case. Just use _signed_ distances.

Comment: oh ok. let me go through it again.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel wrong, Wikipedia does not cover the exterior-point case, not even a mention of it, even though using *signed* distances is valid.

Comment: I went through the whole article again. No mention of it. Once we know the theorem can be extended to the exterior point, we know we can use signed distances but it is not something one can intuitively assume from the wikipedia article.

Comment: Either way it is good to know, something I was not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Connect point $P$ to $A, B, C$. Now you can see that $\triangle ABC = \triangle PAB + \triangle PBC - \triangle PAC = \frac{AB}{2}(h_1 - h_2 + h_3) = 3 AB$

Given equilateral triangle, we also know that $\triangle ABC = \frac{\sqrt3}{4}AB^2 = 3 AB$

That gives you the value of $AB = 4 \sqrt3$ and $\triangle ABC = 12 \sqrt3$

Comment: Corrected the typo

Answer (score 1):

Consider the areas of triangles $APB, BPC, CPA$.

We have the equation

\begin{align}
[\triangle ABC] &= [\triangle APB] - [\triangle CPA] + [\triangle BPC]\\
&=\frac12(ABh_3 - AC h_2 + BC h_1)\\
&=\frac{AB}2(h_1-h_2+h_3)\\
&=3AB
\end{align}

We also have the relation between the side of an equilateral triangle and its area:

$$[\triangle ABC] = \frac{\sqrt 3}4AB^2$$

Now solve for $AB$ and $[\triangle ABC]$.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG let $y=0,y=\sqrt{3}x,y=-\sqrt{3}(x-a)$ be the  eq of  sides  triangle with side of equilateral being $a$.

thus $$h_1+h_3-h_2=1$$ $$|k+\frac{\sqrt{3}h-k}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}h+k +\sqrt{3}a}{2}|=1$$

$$\sqrt{3}a/2=1$$
$$a=?$$
$$area(\Delta)={\sqrt{3}a^2}/4=?$$